# google sheets sparkline to plot growth in values

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get sparkline kind of output for growth in range of values. but not for range of values.

Lets say i have below data in a row.
1, 5, 9, 24, 25.

How to get graph to values of growth as below.
1, 4, 4, 15, 1.

Answer (score 0):

paste 1, 5, 9, 24, 25 into cells A1:A5 and then use the formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SPARKLINE(A2:A5-A1:A4))
```